# WSO2ESB: xml response from endpoint to payload mediator in json format

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator, wso2-esb

Is there any way to convert data service endpoint xml response to json in the payloadFactory mediator?

Here's my source view:

```
<resource methods="GET" uri-template="/get/supplier/{filterQuery}">
      <inSequence>
         <property name="operation" value="view" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full" separator="|">
            <property name="operation" expression="get-property('operation')"/>
            <property name="step" value="request"/>
         </log>
         <property name="filterQuery" expression="get-property('uri.var.filterQuery')" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <log level="full" separator="|">
            <property name="filterQuery" expression="$ctx:filterQuery"/>
         </log>
         <callout serviceURL="http://...:8280/services/myService/" action="urn:getVendorsOperation">
            <source type="envelope"/>
            <target key="response"/>
         </callout>
         <log level="custom" separator="|">
            <property name="MESSAGE" expression="$ctx:response"/>
         </log>
         <property name="res" expression="$ctx:response" scope="default" type="OM"/>
         <log level="full" separator="|">
            <property name="res" expression="get-property('res')"/>
         </log>
         <property name="NO_ENTITY_BODY" scope="axis2" action="remove"/>
         <property name="RESPONSE" value="true" scope="default" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="messageType" value="application/json" scope="axis2" type="STRING"/>
         <property name="contentType" value="application/json" scope="transport" type="STRING"/> 
         <payloadFactory media-type="json">
            <format>{"vendorId": "$1","vendorName": "$2"}</format>
            <args>
               <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/entries/entry/vendorId"/>
            </args>
         </payloadFactory>
         <log level="full" separator="|">
            <property name="operation" expression="$ctx:operation"/>
            <property name="step" value="response"/>
         </log>
         <respond/>
      </inSequence>
```

The result of `res` in the system logs:

```
res = <entries xmlns="http://ws.wso2.org/dataservice/getVendorsQuery"><entry><vendorId>1111</vendorId><vendorName>vendor 1</vendorName></entry><entry><vendorId>2222</vendorId><vendorName>vendor 2</vendorName></entry></entries>|Envelope: <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?><soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://www.w3.org/2003/05/soap-envelope"><soapenv:Body/></soapenv:Envelope>
```

How to get this xml data to payloadFactory and output it as json?

```
<payloadFactory media-type="json">
                <format>{"vendorId": "$1","vendorName": "$2"}</format>
                <args>
                   <arg evaluator="xml" expression="$body/entries/entry/vendorId"/>
                </args>
             </payloadFactory>
```

And also how can I pass the parameters to data service? Its `filterQuery` in my case.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
   <payloadFactory media-type="json">
       <format>$1</format>
       <args>
           <arg evaluator="xml" expression="get-property('res')"/>
       </args>
   </payloadFactory>
```